# Arbitrary file preview in Node-Webkit using JS, Java and/or Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, thumbnails, preview, node-webkit

I want to develop a file-previewer for Node-Webkit. It should be able to handle most file types like `.pdf`, `.pptx`, `.txt`, `.docx`, `.png` +++ Some file types are trivial, like images, but others are harder.

I have been digging around a lot and found a few things that could work. I found [crocodoc](https://crocodoc.com/) which does something similar to what I am thinking of. I also found [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), but as the name suggests, it only does PDFs.

I have considered an approach where I generate image thumbnails of the files before previewing. It is simply a previewer, not a full reader. For this I found the java library [thumbnailer](https://github.com/benjaminpick/java-thumbnailer) which seems to do the trick, but it is in beta and is very inactive.

The tools that I have at my disposal for this project are **Javascript** (in Node-Webkit), **Java** and **Ruby**.

Are there any existing projects that dose this that I can use without paying a license to Crocodoc & Co.? If not, are there any good and active libraries for file-to-thumbnail conversion?